# Optimizing Test Scenarios in Robot Framework: Reducing Redundancy and Enhancing Efficiency

Tags: python, automated-tests, robotframework

I need assistance with Robot Framework. How can I create test scenarios? By test scenarios, I mean combining multiple test cases together. For example, if I have the following test cases:

1.Login backend

2.Add content backend

3.Edit content backend

4.Check frontend content section

And then I have the following test scenarios:
1.Login backend -> Add content backend -> Check frontend content section will update
2.Login backend -> Edit content backend -> Check frontend content section will update

Alright, so now, how can I proceed to write these in Robot Framework? Currently, in the *** Test Cases *** section, I have written out 2 test cases:

1. Login backend -> Add content backend -> Check frontend content section will update
2. Login backend -> Edit content backend -> Check frontend content section will update

Both of these test cases have the Login backend and check frontend content section commands repeated. Is there a way for me to reduce code redundancy? For example, could I write Login Backend and check frontend content section as functions and then call them later in the *** Test Cases *** section?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you could wrap any actions as a `keyword` (the RobotFramework name for functions/methods) and then reuse it.

It is explained in the [User Guide](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#test-case-syntax).

So, `Login backend`, `Edit content backend`, and `Frontend content section should be updated` could be keywords that could be reused.
For example, very high-level:

1. You could have a resource file `backend.robot` with keywords, like:

```
*** Keywords ***
Login backend
  [Arguments]  ...
  ...

Edit content backend
  [Arguments]  ...
  ...

Frontend content section should be updated
  [Arguments]  ...
  ...
```

2. And example of a file with tests, e.g., `sanity.robot`:

```
*** Settings ***
Resource  libs/backend.robot

*** Test Cases ***
Backend content could be added
  Login backend    <arguments here if any>
  Add content backend   <arguments here if any>
  Frontend content section should be updated  <arguments here if any>

Backend content could be edited
  Login backend    <arguments here if any>
  Edit content backend   <arguments here if any>
  Frontend content section should be updated  <arguments here if any>
```